# Wordpress custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

so I am trying to understand the Wordpress custom plugin creation. I have enabled it to activate and show itself with an icon in the menu but I just need to know how to separate the function from the admin dashboard page and what outputs on the theme.

I created a directory for the plugin and two files inside that, one being the functional file and one as included file to separate the code to make it easier to read when creating the config page for the plugin in the dashboard.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Feather Slider
*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_feather_slider' );

function register_feather_slider(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'feather_slider', 
        'Feather Slider', 'manage_options', 
        'feather_slider', // URL Slug
        'feather_slider', // Menu Label
        'dashicons-images-alt2', 50); // Menu icon & Menu Location
}

function feather_slider(){
    include('admin_index.php'); // I want this to handle the plugin config in the dashboard
    add_shortcode('test', 'feather_slider'); // I want this to out put a file which creates the slider.
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question ?

Comment: Do you want to separate the functions from themes to plugins

Comment: Please ask your WordPress related questions here at WordPress.stackexchange.com